# Text is overflowing when using Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a display heading with an image to the left and to the right of the heading. It works great om lg-display but when i make the display smaller the heading text seems to overflow the column to the right making it asymetrical. I would like the images and the text to stay even with smaller screens. Am I doing something wrong with the grid system?

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>farfetch'd | Official Website ‐</title>

  <!--CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="Images\Logo-feather-without-stroke.png">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="float-right" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="feather" style="width:100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="display-4 text-center">farfetch'd</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="feather" style="width:100px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You are using static width for images that can cause issues on smaller screens. You can do it like this: style="width:70%" or whatever percentage that suits you. First try without the width style component, and then add the percentage option as I mentioned. I hope it'll get sorted out. If still issues, do tell me

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad I have added a picture of the result. As you can see the text is still overflowing. It feels like the container becomes to small to handle all three components and prioritises to show the text first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the text to always fit in the middle `div`, one way you can achieve this is using `vw` for length instead of `rem`

**rem:**

> Represents the `font-size` of the root element (typically `<html>`). When used within the root element `font-size`, it represents its initial value (a common browser default is 16px, but user-defined preferences may modify this).

**vw:**

> Equal to 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block.

Check [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for more info on this.
Final result would be:

```css
.heading {
font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>farfetch'd | Official Website ‐</title>

  <!--CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="Images\Logo-feather-without-stroke.png">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="float-right" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="feather" style="width:100px">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="heading text-center">farfetch'd</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="feather" style="width:100px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the default behavior of `h1` tag
you can change this behavior with `overflow-wrap` `overflow` , etc in css